# "Internet Radio" gone from iTunes 12.7

Tags: macos, itunes, mac, streaming, itunes-radio

The "Internet Radio" feature to stream from hundreds of suggested URLs around the world, and allowing me to add my own URL for a stream, is gone from iTunes 12.7.

Did Apple move this feature to a different place in the user-interface, yet again?

Or did Apple remove this feature altogether?

Comment: What's different is that it is now part of "Music" - I don't know why, but for me one of the main reasons to listen to Internet Radio is news, comedies and dramas from around the world, much less music - I feel like embedding Internet Radio into Music seems odd...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The traditional "Internet Radio" feature is not gone from iTunes 12.7.
The feature for offering free for all internet radio streams was not removed from the application but may be hidden and is now named competitively with another "Radio" feature within iTunes.

## Check Restrictions for Traditional "Internet Radio"

It may be invisible to you because you may have a setting active in

```
 iTunes > Preferences > Restrictions > Internet Radio
```

Obviously, the checkbox under `Disable: Internet Radio` needs to be off.

## Re-Add Traditional "Internet Radio" to the Sidebar

More likely is that the new default preferences violate again Apple's own Human Interface Guidelines:

The first "Library Sidebar" for "Music" in its default state is simplified: without Internet Radio visible. And you do not see how to customise it *until* you hit an invisible spot to the right of the sidebar section title called "Library" when your sidebar is set to display "Music". Hovering to the right over an apparently empty spot then reveals an "Edit" option where you can then activate the "Internet Radio" setting. Click "Done" if you are done with your customisations in the same spot to re-hide that user-confuser and traditional "Internet Radio" will be in your sidebar again.

[image: iTunes HIG fail 1]

That gives you the old big list with a tree structure to choose from.

---

## Adding Custom URLs for Traditional "Internet Radio" Streams

Opening a custom stream is accomplished by entering the URL in the box that appears when pressing <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> or choosing the menu item `File` > `Open Stream`.

Adding this permanently seems not possible.
But again: right-clicking into the info area (The Apple logo in the picture) reveals the option to "Create Station".

Interestingly you can also create playlists with those streams to get them organised to your liking.

---

## The new "Apple Music"-"iTunes Store"-"Radio"

An alternative to this method of interfacing to streams is a much more prominent store-like interface for radio stations that looks like it is somehow tied to Apple Music (this one requires from you to give up at least your AppleID or even subscribe to the "Apple Music" service):

[image: iTunes HIG fail 2]
Possible restrictions for that are in iTunes Preferences as a subset under "iTunes Store" and a part of "Apple Music".

Comment: Unfortunately, the "Create Station" feature seems to be broken in iTunes version 12.9.4.94 in macOS Mojave. When choosing that command, Apple popups a dialog trying to yet again sell me an Apple Music subscription. I cancel that dialog, and find no "station" for my opened stream was created. I guess it is time to find a real streaming app. Apple clearly wants to de-emphasize or eliminate open streaming in iTunes.

Answer (score 6):

I still have the "Internet Radio" in iTunes 12.7 – I'm in the screenshot below using an US Apple ID, and I can confirm that I also have the "Internet Radio" with my Danish Apple ID – maybe you just need to re-add the menu item?

[image]